# Why isn't indexOf evaluating the ajax response correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to evaluate an ajax response to know whether the API request succeeded or failed.  I want to remove the add customer link if the request succeeds.

```
<span id='addCustomer'><a class='actionlink' id='addCustomerLink' href='javascript:addCustomer()'>Add Customer</a></span><span id='addCustomerResults'></span>
```

The following text is in all failed requests" "Add Customer request Failed."  The word 'Failed' is not in any successful responses.  indexOf should be catching the word "Failed", but for some reason, it isn't.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'include/ajax.php?action=add',
        data: $('#lead-form').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            $("#addCustomerResults").html(response);

            if (response.indexOf("Failed") != -1) {         
                $('#addCustomer').html("");  // customer created so remove the add customer link
            }
        }
    });
```

The response is a simple text string. Can't figure out why the Add Customer link is being removed whether the response contains the word "Failed" or not.

Comment: capitalization?

Comment: unfortunately not capitalization

Comment: impossible for us to debug this. You need to add some debugging code and see why it is failing.

Comment: is it a json response?  or what text do you get in `#addCustomerResults`?

Comment: This can only happen if a) `response` doesn't contain what you think it contains or b) The string `"Failed"` contains non-printable characters, ot characters that look like ASCII but are not. You have access to your browser's debug tools, only you can actually investigate what the issue is here, we can only guess (which isn't an effective use of anybody's time).

Comment: Are you certain it contains failed?

Comment: this is what gets displayed in the addCustomerResponse: Add Customer request Failed. (TransactionID = 15280175) ACH processing error: Please verify the routing number and try the transaction again, or provide a different payment method

Comment: Have you used your javascript debugger to inspect `response` and see if it _actually_ contains "Failed"?

Comment: Can you reproduce issue at jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: is word "Failed" also in non-failing response too, may be somewhere? Basically what is response text when customer request does not fail?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments everyone.  Had to make two changes.  First, I had a second API event disabled which was causing some text to be included that did have the word Failed in the response.  Second, I changed ("Failed") != -1 to ("Failed") == -1 and it's working as desired now.

Answer (score -2):

Normally a "response" parameter in a "success" callback of AJAX function contains information about response itself, not text (or any other data). If you would like to read text or JSON or any other returned object then you would have to call `response.data`. This is a sample AJAX function.

```
//Making an AJAX call
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "host/resource/",
    data: { name: "MyName", address: "123 Toronto St." },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var returnedData = response.data;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(returnedData));

        //Loop through JSON array
        $.each(returnedData, function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) {
            console.log(indexInArray, valueOfElement);
        });
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

In your case since you are looking for a specific string, you would do something like following.

```
var blnFound = response.data.trim().toUpperCase().indexOf("VALUE_TO_SEARCH") > -1
```

A better solution is to create prototype Javascript methods and call them directly, so you don't have to do all of the above.

Comment: This is 100% dependent on what his `ajax.php` file is returning. It could very well be spitting out the string "Failed". Or it could be JSON. Or it could be a million other things. You can't just assume he is getting some sort of JSON response with a `data` property.

Comment: This completely contradicts [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) which states that the first argument to the `success` function is the data itself: *The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback function, if specified*